# Unity iOS build size on iPhones below 11 is twice as different

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

The screenshot below shows the difference in final build sizes for different devices. Attempts to reduce the size of the game by reducing the graphic elements have not led to tangible results.
Unity 2021.1.10f1

I would be happy to understand the difference and reduce the size of the final build.

I make this screenshot from AppStoreConnect -> TestFlight -> Select Build -> Build Metadata

[image]

Comment: I believe it's the type of compression you are using is not supported on older devices. Which compression are you using on your textures?

Comment: @TEEBQNE I override sprite compression for iOS and use the standard RGB Compressed PVRTC 4 bits format

Comment: @TEEBQNE I also want to say, that once I managed to make a build of 15 megabytes. But exactly the same build, with a changed Build Number, the next time in the app was equal to 70MB

Comment: From your screenshot, that looks like the download size, not the install size. Is that correct? Are all the install sizes the same?

Comment: @TEEBQNE Yes, yes in the screenshot the download size. The install size also differs 99 mb for iPhone below 11 and 86mb for 11 and 12 iPhones

Comment: Interesting. I checked my app and the download size differs in a similar way but install size is all the same or within a negligible amount. I do not know anything about the integrals for iOS products but I'd have to guess each device has to package your app differently for the hardware. As a result the download size is different. I do not think there is anything you can do. Same with android devices, the install and download size can differ from device to device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered an issue that caused my iOS app to double in size on older devices. I am using the UniTask package in my project.
I opened a new thread https://github.com/Cysharp/UniTask/issues/306.